# jquery onchange not firing on touchscreen

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, touch

I have a simple select.

[image]

Now, this select works fine when you use your mouse. But on touchscreen, when you try to tap on the whitespace next to the text of option; it doesn't work.

For example, if you tap on text "W2", it works, but if you tap on the space next to "W2", it doesn't work. Any reasons?

This is the code that gets generated for this select -

[image]

I have an onchange event bind to this select like this -

```
$('#billTypeDropDown select').change(function(){
        showEmpForBilling();
    });
```

Comment: Unless you're using a library that replaces the native `<select>` element with other HTML, this seems like an issue with the Android browser.

Comment: Can you be more specific and tell us which device you're using and what browser? Looks to me like it may be a specific device and/or browser issue.

Comment: And when you tap on the whitespace, does the value change ?

Comment: @Svenskunganka: Its a laptop with touchscreen. An acer laptop.

Comment: @adeneo: When I tap on the whitespace, nothing happens. sometimes onchange fires, sometimes not. When it is not fired, the dropdown stays as it is, and the value of select is not being set.

Comment: @Barmer: Not using any external lib. Its simple HTML select.

Comment: Then that's just how the browser works. If you want more control, use something like jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Or a library like Select2.